# Why can't I view my JLabel added to JPanel while using graphics?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel

I am trying to add a JLabel under the boards that is painted with graphics. I set the x and y position of JLabel somewhere under the board

```
    pName = new JLabel("Yoooooo");
    pName.setBounds(180,500,50,50);
    this.add(pName);
```

However I can't view it when I run the code. What can be the reason?

Edit: Now I can view it thx to Andrew but I can't locate it to the position that I want.

JLabel should be under the board.

```
pName.setBounds(180,500,50,50);
```

seems not working. Why can it be?

```
public class EnemyPanel extends JPanel{

private char enemyBoard[][] = new char[10][10]; //to keep state of squares
private Rectangle r[][] = new Rectangle[10][10];//to give coordinates and boundaries to squares
private int size;
private JLabel pName; 

public EnemyPanel()
{
    size=Constant.rectSize;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            enemyBoard[i][j]='*'; //initialization type
            r[i][j]= new Rectangle(j*size+30,i*size+30, size, size);         
        }
    }
    pName = new JLabel("Yoooooo");
    pName.setBounds(180,500,50,50);
    this.add(pName);

}

 public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
                if(enemyBoard[i][j]=='!'){
                    //hit square's color is changed to white
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                }
                else if(enemyBoard[i][j]=='$')
                    //miss square's color is changed to gray
                     g.setColor(Color.gray);
                else
                    //undiscovered ones are green
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fill3DRect((int)r[i][j].getX() ,(int)r[i][j].getY(),(int)r[i][j].getWidth(), (int)r[i][j].getHeight(), true);

            }
        }
      }


 }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `..extends JPanel{
..
 public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);` should be `"..extends JPanel{
..
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you are wonderful!

Comment: Andrew, It does not care for this pName.setBounds(180,500,50,50); It just puts the label above the graphics. Why is that?

Comment: *"Why is that?"*  Where is that SSCCE?

Comment: I tried SSCCE, can you look at it now, please?

Comment: There is no SSCCE in the question!  Please *read* the linked article carefully.  If you don't understand anything in it, ask me, I am well placed to explain.  But if you are going to ask, make it a specific question or questions.

Comment: Okey, I read it more carefully this time and solved my problem. I'll write it as an answer now. Thank you, Andrew. =)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, and am looking forward to your answer.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. My first problem was that I couldn't view the JLabel component.
   According to Andrew's comment, I solved this problem.
   If you are using other components in your panel, you should use paintComponent other than paint.
2. Secondly, I couldn't view my JLabel where I wanted. So In order to set a specific position to JLabel, you should set the JPanel layout to null.
   this.setLayout(null) solved my second problem.

Comment: It was going well until `this.setLayout(null)`.  Use layouts for a reliable and robust GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Once you override `paint(Graphics g)` you are on your own on painting the component. This means that no matter what other stuff you do outside `paint`, it may not count much as the real paint happens in your custom implementation and not in the default `JPanel` one.

Comment: You can (and most of the time should) always call `super.paint(g);` in your overriden `paint(Graphics g)` method before doing your own paint jobs.